# Azure WebApp ASPNET all DLLs on all deployment slots report 'Access Denied'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, webapp2

We have two deployments, master and development running slightly different builds (master is older and release mode, development is newer and debug mode).

Both are ASP.NET Core compiled for NET 461 (as we use entity framework 6.0 still) Both instances failed at roughly 1AM (UTC+10.30) or 15:30 PM UTC+0.

They also both simultaneously failed on the previous night.

When visiting the websites we receive the following errors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj3EP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFSK1.png

Internal logs show identical failures/times for both deployment slots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNTGu.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCbxo.png

These logs are in UTC+10:30 timezone

Server was manually restarted at 8:02 AM (UTC+10:30) Our internal logging reports ACCESS DENIED when trying to load DLLs that are critical for the application to run.

Our internal logging also shows the application repeatedly being restarted but failing to start The FTP detailed logs do not show anything out of the ordinary.

Pressing 'Restart' in azure does not fix the issue. Stopping the instance, waiting 10 seconds, then pressing start fixes it for roughly 24 hours.

Problem was intermittent previously, now it occurs nightly as of 2 days ago with a break every few days.

Are there any windows system logs that would show what has occurred to cause both deployment slots to fail simultaneously?

What would cause all DLLs to receive access denied errors across all deployment slots simultaneously?

Comment: Linking to [Forum question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1653042f-ed8d-4315-8732-da127e5acdc6/aspnet-all-dlls-on-all-deployment-slots-report-access-denied?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Comment: Support have said my crashes line up with an infrastructure instance change. It is looking like something directly related to the azure platform at this stage. Waiting for a reoccurence to supply them with memory dumps to hopefully find the root cause.